# CSS duplicate selectors

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I picked up a screech of CSS to build a form with visual queues for required fields.

The CSS has a couple of identical selectors that are apparently both important in that removing either effects the form.  Is CSS merging these two some how ?  Thanks for fielding the newbie question. Full listing below.

```
    .required-field-block .required-icon {
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
        margin: -0.25em 0.25em 0em;
        background-color: #E8E8E8;

    snip for brevity
    ....

    }

    .required-field-block .required-icon {
        background-color: transparent;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0em;
        right: 0em;
        z-index: 10;
        margin: 0em;

snip for brevity
....

}
```

---

#### Full Listing

```
.required-field-block {
    position: relative;   
}

.required-field-block .required-icon {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: -0.25em 0.25em 0em;
    background-color: #E8E8E8;
    border-color: #E8E8E8;
    padding: 0.5em 0.8em;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65);
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: normal;
    border-radius: 0.325em;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-transition: background 0.1s linear;
    -moz-transition: background 0.1s linear;
    transition: background 0.1s linear;
    font-size: 75%;
}

.required-field-block .required-icon {
    background-color: transparent;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0em;
    right: 0em;
    z-index: 10;
    margin: 0em;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 0em;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-transition: color 0.2s ease;
    -moz-transition: color 0.2s ease;
    transition: color 0.2s ease;
}

.required-field-block .required-icon:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    right: 1px;
    top: 1px;
    z-index: -1;
    width: 0em;
    height: 0em;
    border-top: 0em solid transparent;
    border-right: 30px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 30px solid transparent;
    border-left: 0em solid transparent;
    border-right-color: inherit;
    -webkit-transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
    -moz-transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
    transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
}

.required-field-block .required-icon .text {
    color: #B80000;
    font-size: 26px;
    margin: -3px 0 0 12px;
}
```

Comment: the second selector will overwrite any of the rules rewritten. Some will 'kill' other like position:absolute will take over adisplay rules. those two blocks can be merged into one. clean up rules you do not need or wich are overwritten.

Answer (score 7):

Both defined styles will be applied, however where the properties overlap the second specified style will take precedence.  If you use Firebug its pretty easy to see what happens:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

From the CSS specification on [cascading order](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#cascade):

> Finally, sort by order specified: if two declarations have the same weight, origin and specificity, the latter specified wins. Declarations in imported style sheets are considered to be before any declarations in the style sheet itself.

So where you have conflicting styles for the same selector in the same style sheet, the last one takes precedence. So in your case, you get `margin: 0em` and `background-color: transparent`.

Answer (score 1):

Your second `margin: 0em;` overrides the first `margin: -0.25em 0.25em 0em;`.

Comment: To add to this, the first background-color will be overwritten by the second.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, sort by order specified: if two declarations have the same weight, origin and specificity, the latter specified wins. Declarations in imported style sheets are considered to be before any declarations in the style sheet itself.
So where you have conflicting styles for the same selector in the same style sheet, the last one takes precedence. So in your case, you get margin: 0em and background-color: transparent.